# How to draw text on Qpixmap with center align

Tags: qt

QPainter paint;
paint.drawText(w,h,Qt::AlginCenter,"Hello");

giving error,no maching function.

Answer (score 6):

```
QPainter painter;
painter.drawText(QRect(0, 0, w, h), Qt::AlignCenter, "Hello");
```

Comment: Was looking for a way to center the text, this worked like a charm!

Answer (score 5):

You shall pass the QPixmap to the QPainter in the constructor or in the begin function:

```
QPixmap pixmap;
// ...

QPainter painter( &pixmap );

// OR
QPainter painter;
painter.begin( &pixmap );
```

Then you shall choose one of the followings:

```
void drawText( const QRectF& rectangle, int flags, const QString& text, QRectF* boundingRect = 0 )
void drawText( const QRect& rectangle, int flags, const QString& text, QRect* boundingRect = 0 )
void drawText( int x, int y, int width, int height, int flags, const QString& text, QRect* boundingRect = 0 )
```

So if you want to define the alignment you need to pass a rectangle in which you want to draw your text.

You forget to define the top left corner of the rectangle, you just passed the width and the height arguments to the draw function.